# TypeError: cannot use the given object as a weak map key while using Swiper.js in Firefox

Tags: lightning, lightning-apps, error, unexpectedexception, firefox

Getting below error in Firefox, when using [Swiper.js](http://idangero.us/swiper/) in a simple Lightning​  App.

[image]

> TypeError: cannot use the given object as a weak map key throws at
>   https://rio-education-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/1bO4dJePbDnoI-_VdhdsEQ/aura_prod.js:4:277

This doesn't seem to appear in other browsers ( Microsoft Edge, Chrome), they worked perfect. Has anyone encountered similar before? Any idea why it happens in Firefox only.

My code as below.

**Markup**

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <aura:attribute name="mySwiperObj" type="object" description="for swiper navigation" />
    <div aura:id="termMapItems" class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide"  >AAAA<lightning:icon iconName="action:approval" size="large"/></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"  >BBBB<lightning:icon iconName="action:approval" size="large"/></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"  >CCC<lightning:icon iconName="action:approval" size="large"/></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" >DDDD<lightning:icon iconName="action:approval" size="large"/></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.Swiper + '/css/swiper.min.css'}" scripts="{!$Resource.Swiper + '/js/swiper.min.js'}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.loadSwiper}" />
</aura:application>
```

**JS Controller**

```
({
    loadSwiper: function(component, event, helper){
        console.log('load swiper called!');
        var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
            initialSlide: 2,
            effect: 'coverflow',
            grabCursor: true,
            centeredSlides: true,
            slidesPerView: 'auto',
            coverflowEffect: {
                rotate: 50,
                stretch: 0,
                depth: 100,
                modifier: 1,
                slideShadows : false,
            },
            pagination: {
                el: '.swiper-pagination'
            },
            navigation: {
                nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
                prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
            },
        });
        console.log('2 swiper object: '+    mySwiper);  // mySwiper is initialized, but not working in firefox :/
        component.set("v.mySwiperObj", mySwiper);
    }
})
```

[This Mozilla issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?format=default&id=1449485) looks similar, but don't feel they are related.
Appreciate any help/thoughts to workaround/fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Given that it's only in FireFox, it's most likely a FireFox bug. You might try submitting an issue on [Swiper's GitHub](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper) and see if they can fix it on their end.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, moved <ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.Swiper + '/css/swiper.min.css'}" scripts="{!$Resource.Swiper + '/js/swiper.min.js'}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.loadSwiper}" /> and set API version to 38 and that fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this workaround,

Moved below line,

```
<ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.Swiper + '/css/swiper.min.css'}" scripts="{!$Resource.Swiper + '/js/swiper.min.js'}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.loadSwiper}" />
```

To the top and also set API version to 38 and that fixed the issue for me.

Also, in the real program I had to remove below JS code,

```
component.find("viewCssdBtn").set("v.class","slds-button slds-align_absolute-center ");
```

and utilized class with Inline IFs.

Hope someone would benefit from it. Also would appreciate and welcome any suggestions to make it better. 
Cheers!