# Lightning app does not want to run in Firefox

Tags: lightning, browser, firefox

My Lightning app does not want to run in Firefox. The problem is in auto-generated code:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
"meta":{
    "name":"zced$RPGFlowComponent",
    "extends":"markup://aura:component"
  }
```

Did someone have the same problem? How did you tackle it?

I am using `Firefox 61.0.1 (64-bit)`. The app works fine in Chrome and Opera.

Comment: Does it work on chrome?  Can you post your code in explicit way? can you place a debugger and see at which line does it fail?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: cannot use the given object as a weak map key while using Swiper.js in Firefox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/218404/typeerror-cannot-use-the-given-object-as-a-weak-map-key-while-using-swiper-js-i)

Comment: I'm not sure the proposed duplicate is sufficiently general. I've experienced the same issue with Leaflet.js in Firefox and haven't found a clear general explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Firefox:

> A C++ object that is exposed to JS can have its reflector used as a
>   key in a weak map. Because a weak map does not keep its keys alive,
>   this means that the reflector can be discarded if it has no other
>   references aside from the C++ object, which will in turn remove its
>   weak map entry. If the C++ object can be accessed again later from JS,
>   it will get a new reflector which will have no weak map entry. This is
>   bad because it means some internal implementation detail has resulted
>   in data loss that is visible to JS. (Side note: this is also an issue
>   for cross compartment wrappers, which is handled by another
>   mechanism.)

DOM objects are C++ objects in this context, as opposed to JavaScript objects.

Use [Firefox Nightly](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/channel/desktop/?utm_campaign=blog-nav&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=blog.nightly.mozilla.org#nightly) as a temporary workaround until Firefox 64 is released.

**References**

- [gecko-dev/test_paris_weakmap_keys.html at 53217795fec93a1dff225e6f9bfd48c508039470 · mozilla/gecko-dev · GitHub](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/53217795fec93a1dff225e6f9bfd48c508039470/js/xpconnect/tests/mochitest/test_paris_weakmap_keys.html)
- [Bug 1493237 - Use a test-only non-nsISupports wrapper cached WebIDL c… · mozilla/gecko-dev@5321779 · GitHub](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/commit/53217795fec93a1dff225e6f9bfd48c508039470)
- [Firefox Bug 1449485 - cannot use the given object as a weak map key](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1449485)
- [Firefox Bug 1351501 - Can't use non-nsISupports cycle collected WebIDL objects as WeakMap keys](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1351501)
- [The first official 20180922 builds are out • mozillaZine Forums](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=3041738)